# Sharepoint 2007 permissions needed to View webpart in page but not edit page?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, permissions, web-parts

I have the following scenario:

- I have a list of custom items. Users with "Contribute" permission level can add and edit items on this list.
- I created a blank webpart page, and added to the page a webpart to view the custom list.
  The webpart page is stored on a "Pages" document library.

This works fine, except that I don't want contributors to mess with the webpart and modify the shared page. So in order to have "Modify shared webpart" link dissapear, I broke Inheritance on the Pages document library and set permissions of contributors to "Read only".

However, this does not work as expected and when users access the web part page, the whole webpart is not displayed.

I have troubleshooted the problem creating custom permission levels and the permission that is needed to the default "Read Only" level is the "edit items" permission on the Pages list.

However, this permission gives the user of editing the page and changing the webpart.

How can I achieve the correct permission set? I need to have the page as "read only" for most users, but still have them view the webpart (and add and edit items on the original custom list).

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the page with the web part been checked in, published, and approved?

It might not be a permissions issue, it could be that Read Only users are seeing the old, published version of the page (a version that does not contain the web part).

Comment: That's correct! I just had to check out the file again and publish a mayor version, and the webpart started appearing as desired. 

Thanks a lot!